# Script to check a shared Exchange calendar and then email detail

Tags: email, exchange, scripting, calendar

We're running Server and Exchange 2003 here.

There's a shared calendar which HR keep up-to-date detailing staff who are on leave.  I'm looking for a VB Script (or alternate) which will extract the "appointment" titles of each item for the current day and then email the detail to a mail group, in doing so notifying the group with regard to which staff are on leave for the day.

The resulting email body should be:

---

Staff on leave today:
Mike Davis
James Stead

---

@Paul Robichaux - ADO is the way I went for this in the end, here are the key component for those interested:

```
Dim Rs, Conn, Url, Username, Password, Recipient
Set Rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

'Configurable variables
Username = "Domain\username" ' AD domain\username
Password = "password" ' AD password
Url = "file://./backofficestorage/domain.com/MBX/username/Calendar" 'path to user's mailbox and folder
Recipient = "email@address.com"

Conn.Provider = "ExOLEDB.DataSource"

Conn.Open Url, Username, Password
Set Rs.ActiveConnection = Conn


Rs.Source = "SELECT ""DAV:href"", " & _
" ""urn:schemas:httpmail:subject"", " & _
" ""urn:schemas:calendar:dtstart"", " & _
" ""urn:schemas:calendar:dtend"" " & _
"FROM scope('shallow traversal of """"') "
Rs.Open
Rs.MoveFirst

strOutput = ""
Do Until Rs.EOF

    If DateDiff("s", Rs.Fields("urn:schemas:calendar:dtstart"), date) >= 0 And DateDiff("s", Rs.Fields("urn:schemas:calendar:dtend"), date) < 0 Then
        strOutput = strOutput & "<p><font size='2' color='black' face='verdana'><b>" & Rs.Fields("urn:schemas:httpmail:subject") & "</b><br />" & vbCrLf
        strOutput = strOutput & "<b>From: </b>" & Rs.Fields("urn:schemas:calendar:dtstart") & vbCrLf
        strOutput = strOutput & "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>To: </b>" & Rs.Fields("urn:schemas:calendar:dtend") & "<br /><br />" & vbCrLf
    End If

    Rs.MoveNext
Loop

Conn.Close

Set Conn = Nothing
Set Rec = Nothing
```

After that, you can do what you like with srtOutput, I happened to use CDO to send an email:

```
Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objMessage.Subject = "Subject"
objMessage.From = "email@address.com"
objMessage.To = Recipient
objMessage.HTMLBody = strOutput
objMessage.Send
```

S

Comment: Which version of Exchange?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the Collaboration Data Objects (CDO) libraries. They're not all that hard to use. Take a look at [this sample](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Dot_Net_2005.aspx). Essentially, you'll need to open the calendar folder by using a user with appropriate permissions, get the day's appointments, and iterate through them.